# How to send mail in Java using same mechanism like in PHP mail()

Tags: java, email, send

I'm having trouble in sending mail from my application. I can't use simple SMTP server on my application. And have no idea how to deal with sending mails in JAVA. I'm supposed to use same/similar mechanism like PHP's mail() uses. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) API, and as PHP's mail() requires, it will need an SMTP server to send that email.

If you require an SMTP server I suggest searching Google for an SMTP server for your operating system or maybe you could use an SMTP server provided by your ISP or server host.

Comment: I can't just use SMTP to send mails. I need some mechanism similar to PHP one which uses system sendmail to deliver mails.

Comment: But PHP's mail() does use SMTP.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I find STMP configuration which is used by PHP's mail function? This is configured in php.ini file right?

Comment: Yes that should be in the php.ini file, and by default it will probably direct to localhost.

Answer (score 5):

The [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) provides support for sending and receiving e-mails. The API provides a plug-in architecture where vendor’s implementation for their own proprietary protocols can be dynamically discovered and used at the run time. Sun provides a reference implementation and its supports the following protocols:

- Internet Mail Access Protocol (IMAP)
- Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)
- Post Office Protocol 3 (POP 3)

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String text;

    public SendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String text){
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String from = "abc@gmail.com";
            String to = "xyz@gmail.com";
            String subject = "Test";
            String message = "A test message";
            SendMail sendMail = new SendMail(from, to, subject, message);
            sendMail.send();
    }

    public void send(){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
        InternetAddress toAddress = null;
        try {
            fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
            toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
            simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
            simpleMessage.setText(text);    
            Transport.send(simpleMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice but I cant just use SMTP server in order to send mail because there is none available. But still there is available to use PHP's mail() method which use system sendmail to deliver mails from applications. I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: PHP `mail()` does use SMTP.

Comment: @Prakhar I don't see why not.  While I haven't tried it out with this code, there is no authentication process done to prove you are who you say you are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35152/discussion-between-prakhar-and-syb0rg)

Comment: do i have to setup a Smtp server

Comment: @Prakhar No, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaMail api with a local SMTP server like [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/server/), so after installing and running James server, you can set the SMTP server ip to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm supposed to use same/similar mechanism like PHP's mail() uses.

You can't, because it doesn't exist. If that's the requirement, get it changed.

> Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it.

See the JavaMail API.