# Implementing mailing properly in my java application

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am trying to implement mailing system within my java application and I am not sure how send the emails so that they are respected by the mail servers and their spam filters. I will be sending emails with "finish your registration", "forgotten password" and notifications which happen within the user's account.

At the moment I am sending the emails normally via my gmail account (I don't necessarily need to use gmail). However after a few sent mails, I get to point that gmail stops delivering my mails unless I log in into the gmail web application. I send it via classic Java mail API:

```
// settings
properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", smtpPort);
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSLSocketFactory.class.getName());
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

// sending email via smtp
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
message.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
Transport.send(message);
```

So do I have to use my own SMTP server? What about the default sendmail linux command, why would I need SMTP? From PHP we can send email directly without SMTP, can I achieve this with Java as well?

```
<?php mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); ?>
```

Which of these techniques is the most correct? How to use these services so that they are trustful to others? What can I do to be not marked as spam?

Comment: show us your research

Comment: PHP uses SMTP server defined in php.ini :)

Comment: I think it rather uses the unix sendmail function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few questions, so here are a few answers:

Try adding the following to your code -- they make things work better in Gmail:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```

and make sure your Authenticator is something like this:

```
javax.mail.Authenticator auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){ 
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);   
    }
};
```

Google still has some sending limits. They are pretty high, but that's all subjective. If that doesn't work, here are a few more answers:

Java will allow you to send mail straight from your application. However, this will rarely if ever make it past email spam filters. So even though you *can* send it without the SMTP, it is not recommended. One of the main reasons these emails are blocked is because the ip address that sent the email isn't one of the valid [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for that domain. SMTP makes it possible to send mail from a "trusted" source, and usually that means making it past spam filters.

With all that in mind, your other option, as you mentioned, is to make a local email server. However, that email server needs an MX Record for the "from" domain. [Google provides a pretty comprehensive set of instructions for how to set that with the different DNS providers (all listed down the left side)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33353?hl=en&ref_topic=1611273). i.e. if your from address is you@yourdomain.com, then yourdomain.com needs to have an MX Record pointing to the server that hosts your email server.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Install a local SMTP server (if not already present) so you can telnet to port 25. For Ubuntu postfix is nice.

Then use localhost as the SMTP server in your java programs.

Note that most modern servers want recipient or sender to "belong" to the server to accept the mail.  This is to avoid spammer misuse.

---

EDIT: You can invoke sendmail directly.  You just need to provide a properly MIME-encoded message as the body and pipe it in through stdin.  You should be able to get JavaMail to provide you with that body, but I do not have personal experience with that.

Comment: If you still want to use gmail you most likely need to conform to their terms of use, or give them money.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question: 1. Why would I need SMTP server, where there is sendmail which does not use it? 2. Which technique is the most correct to be trustful to spam filters?

Comment: First of all you have a bunchload of questions, not just "how do I invoke /usr/bin/sendmail properly"!   Secondly, the header asks "how do I implement mailing properly in my Java application" and my answer addressed that!

Comment: Does it mean you don't read the message body and just start answering what is written in the header?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around on the question:

[How to send mail in Java using same mechanism like in PHP mail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803761/how-to-send-mail-in-java-using-same-mechanism-like-in-php-mail)

I think I have found a few answers for you:

> Do I have to use my own SMTP server?

**Yes, you do. But as mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803761/how-to-send-mail-in-java-using-same-mechanism-like-in-php-mail) post, you could use [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/server/) as a server.**

> From PHP we can send email directly without SMTP, can I achieve this with Java as well?

**The PHP `mail()` function also uses SMTP. You can find the SMTP server configuration in the `php.ini` file.**

You say that you are using the classic Java API are you referring to [this one?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) If not, then you can try that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with an SMTP server was a simpler solution for me. So I'd suggest installing a local SMTP server.
Well if you have the access to DNS records for the domain you're sending mails from, create a SPF record, and point it to the IP address of the SMTP server. Email services then will think that emails are coming from a legit server unless you send too many emails to the same user and get your IP address in a black list.